# Firebase authentication: sendEmailVerification automatically verifies the user's email

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm starting to use Firebase Authentication in my Next.js app.

I've enabled Email/Password authentication method and I've created the user directly from the Firebase console. I don't want to allow user sign up yet.

I've seen that the user email is not verified by default, so I started implementing the logic to do so with the provided [sendEmailVerification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) method, just pretty simple code within the event of a button click:

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
  if (!user) {
    console.warn(`Shouldn't request a verification email if user is not logged in!.`)
    return
  }
  await sendEmailVerification(user)
}
```

But surprisingly, after that, the user's email gets automatically verified, and no email is even sent.

What am I missing?

Comment: Sending a verification email does not automatically verify that user's email address. There must be something else going on. --- If the user doesn't receive the email, it likely ended up in their spam folder, or in a spam filter along the way to their mailbox.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, that should be the desired behaviour, strange, I deleted the user, cleared the cache, reload the page, created the user again. I don't know. 

At last I've tested with a different email provider (hotmail) and now it works as expected, I've recreated the first user, and it now works fine, and email is received.

I don't understand, I haven't changed anything on the code, and even the UserCredential object itself was showing emailVerified: true.

Comment: If it depends on the email provider, are you sure you're using the email+password provider and not an OAuth provider. For the latter the fact that some email addresses are auto-verified is expected. Either way: it's much more likely that we can help if you show the [complete-but-minimal code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is it is *very* unlikely that the problem is caused by sending the verification email.

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. No other sign-in provider is setup in the project page, just email/password.

The only thing I've configured is the custom action URL to http://localhost:3000/account/actions instead of the default.. ‍♂️